# How to change the length of Y axis in robinhood/spark Library Sample?

Tags: android, github, graph

[GitHub Library](https://github.com/robinhood/spark)

1. By default the the range of Y axis is between 0-1 , i want to change it to 0-2000?
2. How to show the value of X axis in layout when scrubbed?

Main Activity

```html
 sparkView = findViewById(R.id.sparkview);

        adapter = new RandomizedAdapter();
        sparkView.setAdapter(adapter);
        sparkView.setScrubListener(new SparkView.OnScrubListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrubbed(Object value) {
                if (value == null) {
                    scrubInfoTextView.setText(R.string.scrub_empty);
                } else {
                    scrubInfoTextView.setText(getString(R.string.scrub_format, value));
                }
            }
        });
```

SparkAdapter

```html
  private final DataSetObservable observable = new DataSetObservable();

 
public abstract int getCount();
@NonNull
public abstract Object getItem(int index);

public float getX(int index) {
    return index;
}
public abstract float getY(int index);
@NonNull
public RectF getDataBounds() {
    final int count = getCount();
    final boolean hasBaseLine = hasBaseLine();

    float minY = hasBaseLine ? getBaseLine() : Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float maxY = hasBaseLine ? minY : -Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float minX = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float maxX = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final float x = getX(i);
        minX = Math.min(minX, x);
        maxX = Math.max(maxX, x);

        final float y = getY(i);
        minY = Math.min(minY, y);
        maxY = Math.max(maxY, y);
    }
    // set values on the return object
    return createRectF(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
}
@VisibleForTesting
RectF createRectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    return new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
}
public boolean hasBaseLine() {
    return false;
}
public float getBaseLine() {
    return 0;
}
public final void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    observable.notifyChanged();
}
public final void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
    observable.notifyInvalidated();
}
public final void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    observable.registerObserver(observer);
}
public final void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    observable.unregisterObserver(observer);
}
```

I want output like this [Image](https://ibb.co/GkgymTf)  where on Scrubbing its shows Y and X axis both.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can change the Y value supplied to the SparkView by supplying your own SparkAdapter subclass and returning whatever values you want from the `getY()` method. SparkView will automatically scale whatever values your SparkAdapter provides it to fit within the View boundaries.

MySparkAdapter.java

```
public class MySparkAdapter extends SparkAdapter {

  // pass your real data into the constructor
  public MySparkAdapter(...) {
    // store your data
  }

  @Override
  public float getY() {
    // return the y value from your data
  }

  ... // other override methods
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
sparkView = findViewById(R.id.sparkview);
sparkView.setAdapter(new MySparkAdapter(...));
```

2) The `new SparkView.OnScrubListener()` will receive a call to `onScrubbed()` every time the scrub value is changed. All you need to do in there is take the `Object` (which is the same object that your `MySparkAdapter` returns from `getObject()`), and use it to update your UI.

Hope that helps!